# Access 2013 file to open in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003, ms-access-2013

I made `Access Form` which was working fine in **Access 2013 and Access 2007** until I add some new features(I don't remember what) to it.

After adding them, it keeps giving me error `"Unrecognize file format"` when I try to run it in Access 2007. Meanwhile it runs fine in Access 2013.

I want to ask if there exists some software to convert Access 2013 file to Access 2007? Or is there any way make it compatible to 2003? When I Save As 2003 file it don't because of some added features.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You could try using Access' `Application.SaveAsText` in 2013 and `Application.LoadFromText` in 2003.

Even if this doesn't work directly, if you have an older version that does work, you could compare the differences between the text files the two versions of Access produce, as `SaveAsText` produces (for the most part) human readable output; the only unreadable parts are typically images.

Comment: Where to use `Application.SaveAsText` ?

Comment: In the VBA Immediate window or in VBA code.  Intellisense will show you what parameters it is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen to me during development on A2010 and deployment on A2007. The possibilities are explained on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cc907897.aspx). It is likely that you added an Empty Cell control to a form that had a VBA module (or added a module to a form with an Empty Cell control). I did this unknowingly by inserting a row into the AutoHeader that is created in forms by the Form Wizard.

Follow the steps at the bottom row of Table 2 to rectify this.